# How to reference a canvas that is a child of a gameobject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a prefab I instantiate during play, that has a child canvas rendered in world space. I need this child canvas to display some floating UI elements specific to each instance of the prefab.

However I don't know how to access the child canvas. I usually access child objects using GetChild, but it doesn't seem to be working for the canvas (it throws a transform out of bounds error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new script in the top most gameobject of the prefab.

```
public Transform Canvas;
```

Drop the canvas onto it. Then when you instantiate the prefab you can do this:

```
var obj = Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation) as Transform;
var canvas = obj.GetComponent<MyScript>().Canvas;
```

And that's it. Easy access from a top level script.

Comment: Thank you. As you said it was quite easy...not sure how I confused myself but appreciate the help.